# How to Convert a lengthy BinaryString into HexString in java

Tags: java

I have a requirement to parse a lengthy binarystring into hexstring, i tried with the methods available in the wrapper classess Integer,BigInteger,Long but the coversion is not yielding the desired outcome.

the BinaryString i have is:

```
String binary ="1011110010001000111100011100011100";
```

now i need to convert into Hex and then have to parse.

any help is a really greatefull and appreaciated..!

Thanks in advance

Comment: "the coversion is not yielding the desired outcome." <-- example of failures?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `BigInteger` to convert between bases (in your case binary = base 2 and hex = base 16):

```
String binary ="1011110010001000111100011100011100";
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(binary, 2); //number is in base 2
String hex = bi.toString(16); //convert to base 16
System.out.println(hex);
```

outputs:

```
2f223c71c
```

Comment: Yup, but the OP seems to say this is failing... Of course, no code, no proof.